# Ubuntu not booting after trying to install Nvidia CUDA Drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

My machine running Ubuntu has been giving an ACPI bios error since a while. However, it usually shows the error while booting then continue as usual. Picture of the complete error (the cleaning part after force shutting down the pc using the power button:
[image]

I was trying to install the CUDA drivers and I had a lot of dependency errors, even the system settings started crashing every time I try to open them saying I should try restarting my computer. When I did, it was stuck on the error and did not boot as usual. I tried disabling the acpi by accessing the grub menu and the error stopped showing but I got another error:

[image]

Suggestions I found to solve this include enabling ACPI (which makes me go back to the first error) and waiting (which did not work). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you well backed up?  Re-install may be easier than cleanup.  What version CUDA and Ubuntu? Can you get to a virtual terminal with ctrl+alt+F3  (normally the login is on F1 and the desktop on F2)?  If not, you'll have to use a live media to access your root filesystem for cleanup. Remove any nouveau blacklist in any file in /etc/modprobe.d, Purge *nvidia* (which may remove CUDA for no good reason I can think of). Remove any graphics PPA, apt update, Then clean install the recommended  Nvidia driver from standard repos. CUDA install from the run file, see ans 1077061 and 1219761.

Comment: I do not care much about the data on the machine. I think the problem is BIOS related, last I checked I could not access the BIOS using F2. Is there another way I could reinstall the OS? Moreover, the error has been there since the operating system was installed so how would a reinstall fix it?

Comment: The ACPI errors are nothing to worry about, you have a video driver problem brought about by some (unnecessary) CUDA dependencies. A clean install of OS followed by install Nvidia from Ubuntu restricted repos, followed by CUDA .run script where you override all offers of Nvidia and override all system locations for libs. F2 not working to get to UEFI Setings/BIOS is not an Ubuntu problem.